# GKE node pool dont autoscaling to 0 nodes

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I made a gke cluster using Terraform

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "airflow_prd" {
  name = "airflow-prd"
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count = 1
  network = var.vpc
  location = var.zone_prd
  subnetwork = var.subnet_prd
  project = "xxxxxx"
  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_endpoint = false
    enable_private_nodes = true
    master_ipv4_cidr_block = "172.13.0.0/28"
    master_global_access_config {
      enabled = true
    }
  }
  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name = ""
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "default_prd" {
  name       = "default"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.airflow_prd.name
  initial_node_count = 2
  location = var.zone_prd

  node_config {
    machine_type = "e2-small"
    oauth_scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    service_account = "xxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }

  autoscaling {
    max_node_count = 4
    min_node_count = 2
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "airflow_prd" {
  name       = "airflow"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.airflow_prd.name
  initial_node_count = 0
  location = var.zone_prd

  node_config {
    machine_type = "e2-standard-8"
    oauth_scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    service_account = "xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }

  autoscaling {
    max_node_count = 1
    min_node_count = 0
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "etl_32_prd" {
  name       = "etl-32"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.airflow_prd.name
  initial_node_count = 0
  location = var.zone_prd

  node_config {
    machine_type = "e2-standard-8"
    oauth_scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    service_account = "xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }

  autoscaling {
    max_node_count = 4
    min_node_count = 0
  }
}
```

The problem is with node pool etl-32. It automatically creates nodes when needed. When it is no longer needed, the number of nodes is reduced to 1, not to 0, which is what I want. How to make it go down to 0? The system pods are all in node pool default_prd, which always has 2 nodes

Comment: In the GCP console if you go to GKE > Cluster > Nodes does that Node Pool show 0-4 Nodes Per zone? Below node pools select the one ETL 32 node > Are there any pods showing up where the namespace is not kube-system?

Comment: There are only own kubernet pods, none created by me

Comment: When you select the ETL Node Pool, click edit, is cluster autoscaling enabled and do you see minimum = 0 and maximum = 4?

Comment: Yes, minimun 0 and max 4